# Scala Reassigment to Val with Class (Setters/Getters)

Tags: scala

I've made a custom class in Scala that looks like this:

```
class DQOpsStoreProfileStatusS extends Serializable{
  final val serialVersionUID = 1l
  private var _id:Int = _
  private var _runStatusId:Int = _
  private var _lakeHdfsPath:String = _

  def id = this._id
  def id_ = (_id:Int) = this._id = _id

  def runStatusId = this._runStatusId
  def runStatusId_ = (_runStatusId:Int) = this._runStatusId = _runStatusId

  def lakeHdfsPath = this._lakeHdfsPath
  def lakeHdfsPath_ = (_lakeHdfsPath:String) = this._lakeHdfsPath = _lakeHdfsPath
}
```

I reference this class in another object that looks like this:

```
 var colResult = new DQOpsStoreProfileStatusS
        colResult.fieldIndex = curIndex
        colResult.lakeHdfsPath = inputFileLocation
```

My two setters are complaining of "Reassignment to Val". I have looked through a bunch of examples and cant figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method names for setters should end in `_=` without the space: `def id_=(_id:Int)` etc. You are instead defining methods without arguments called `id_`, `runStatusId_` and `lakeHdfsPath_`.